# C# Json Interface serialization parent-child

Tags: c#, json, serialization, interface

this might have a easy/quick solution, but from my investigation I didn't manage to find it.

```
   public interface IBaseMessage
   {

   }

   public interface IRefreshMessage : IBaseMessage
   {

   }
```

Both are implemented by concrete classes in a Library.Message

They are stored inside a `List<IBaseMessage>` and when I serialize the object to be send over the network (one by one) it is marked as `IBaseMessage` even tough some are `IRefrehMessage`

Issue: on deserialization (on another PC) they are reconstructed as `IBaseMessage` and all the information from `IRefreshMessage` is lost.

Assumption: I believe there must be some JSON class attribute that allows me to specify into what to be serialized?

Thank you, and sorry for a rather silly question

Edit:

Using this class to serialize/deserialize:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
public class JMessage
{
   public Type Type { get; set; }
   public JToken Value { get; set; }

   public static JMessage FromValue<T>(T value)
   {
       return new JMessage { Type = typeof(T), Value = JToken.FromObject(value) };
   }

   public static string Serialize(JMessage message)
   {
      return JToken.FromObject(message).ToString();
   }

   public static JMessage Deserialize(string data)
   {
      return JToken.Parse(data).ToObject<JMessage>();
   }
```

Once is calls

```
string data = JMessage.Serialize(JMessage.FromValue(message));
```

I get:

```
{
  "Type": "Universal_Tool_Manager.Messages.Message.Interfaces.IBaseMessage, Universal Tool Manager.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
  "Value": {
    "Propagation": 2,
    "State": 0
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Aside from lacking a [mcve] (as mjwills already mentioned), it is entirely unclear whether your problem is with the serialization (like, the json data not containing IRefreshMessage-specific properties or containing incorrect type information with regard to IBaseMessage/IRefreshMessage) or whether the deserializer just ignores those IRefreshMessage-specific properties in the json data. Please **edit** and improve your question to add such crucial information necessary to understand the problem...

Comment: Take a look at [JsonSubTypes](https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the wrong question here :)

```
   public static JMessage FromValue<T>(T value)
    {
        return new JMessage { Type = **typeof(T)**, Value = JToken.FromObject(value) };
    }
```

The issue was on typeof(T) which of course it will always return the base interface IBaseInterface since i'm using a

```
List<IBaseInterface>,
```

The solution was to use value.GetType(),

sorry for the rookie mistake

Comment: Please mark the solution as answer so that the question is closed :-)

Answer (score 1):

JSON.NET allows you to specify how to handle serialization and deserialization using `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new List<Test>
        {
            new Test() {Hello = "Hi"},
            new TestDerived() {Hello = "hello", Second = "World"}
        };
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() 
        {
             TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
        };
        var text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, settings);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Test>>(text, settings);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Hello { get; set; }
}

public class TestDerived : Test
{
    public string Second { get; set; }
}
```

In this sample the generated JSON will contain a name of the actual type which was serialized and JSON.NET will use this information to deserialize back to the correct derived type - `data[1]` is `TestDerived` in my example code.

To use `JsonSerializerSettings` with `FromObject` and `Parse` methods, you will need to create an instance of `JsonSerializer`:

```
var serializer = sonSerializer.Create(settings);
JToken.FromObject(o, serializer)
//and
JToken.Parse(data).ToObject<JMessage>(serializer);
```